# jQuery height animation at the top, not the bottom of an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

HTML/CSS/JS here: http://jsfiddle.net/_mtr/XGe8d/2/

My problem is that the animation is taking place at the bottom of the element, not the top. I figure it's an issue with my CSS positioning, but I can't suss it out. And ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another solution

http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/s26wr/

Comment: Not perfect, but pretty close. Puts me on the right course, at least. Thanks.

Comment: You still need to add .stop(true, true) before your animation unless you want it to queue to infinity whenever someone hovers rapidly back and forth over your menu options.

Comment: Yeah, it's included in the actual project. My jsfiddle was just enough to get the idea across. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").hover(

    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'paddingTop': '+=10px'
        }), $(this).animate({
            'paddingTop': '-=10px'
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, one option is to animate `padding-top` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGe8d/4/).  I added position: relative to your css and used top().  I also added .stop(true, true) to eliminate queuing issues.